# Different outputs when printing Python bytearray of list

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, printing

I am trying to convert a list of integers to bytearray in Python 2.7

input code:

```
bytearray([1,2,120,120])
```

output:

```
bytearray(b'\x01\x02xx')
```

But when I try to "print" the same bytearray, I am getting some wired characters.

input code:

```
print bytearray([1,2,120,120])
```

output:

```
??xx
```

Are they both same? What is the reason behind this?

Comment: `print bytearray([1,2,120,120])` --- what do you expect to see as a result here actually?

Comment: @zerkms I am expecting an answer like the first case: bytearray(b'\x01\x02xx'). But when I write some function to convert list of integers to bytearray and call that function somewhere else, I am getting this wired character string as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get `bytearray(b'\x01\x02xx')` you need to use the `__repr__` method of a bytearray object:

```
print repr(bytearray([1,2,120,120]))
```

By default `__str__` in invoked, that returns a string representation of a byte array. And that string contains the `\x01\x02` that are not printable characters, hence you see question marks.

References:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr